# Tower of Hanoi using recursion

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I have no idea about [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi). I want to write a program on this using recursion.

Comment: Unless you say more, this sounds a lot like a homework question. Even at that, it's not much of a question. Can you say a bit more? What have you tried, where are you having a problem?

Comment: Go right ahead then! It's fun! I've worked through that assignement (using Pascal) and enjoyed it very much. ... (or were you asking for us to help?)

Comment: you should check out [this answer in - Tower of Hanoi: Recursive Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259294/7541700)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi):

> The Tower of Hanoi or Towers of Hanoi
>   (also known as The Towers of Brahma)
>   is a mathematical game or puzzle. It
>   consists of three rods, and a number
>   of disks of different sizes which can
>   slide onto any rod. The puzzle starts
>   with the disks neatly stacked in order
>   of size on one rod, the smallest at
>   the top, thus making a conical shape.

Check out the [recursive solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution).

Answer (score 7):

Another homework assignment. Pass your teacher's A to me ;)

Source: http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/~andrew/hanoi/rechelp.html
Bonus: a step-by-step [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_6nsViVM00).

---

### A little bit about the Tower of Hanoi

An analysis of this and a discussion of the (invented) mythology and of the four peg version can be found in the [rec.puzzles FAQ](ftp://ftp.cs.ruu.nl/pub/NEWS.ANSWERS/puzzles/archive/) look for [induction/hanoi.s](ftp://ftp.cs.ruu.nl/pub/NEWS.ANSWERS/puzzles/archive/induction)

The Tower of Hanoi problem has a nice recursive solution.

**Working out recursive solutions**

To solve such problems ask yourself: "if I had solved the *n-1* case could I solve the *n* case?"

If the answer to this question is positive you proceed under the outrageous assumption that the *n-1* case has been solved. Oddly enough this works, so long as there is some base case (often when *n* is zero or one) which can be treated as a special case.

**How to move n rings from pole A to pole C?**

If you know how to move *n-1* rings from one pole to another then simply move *n-1* rings to the spare pole - there is only one ring left on the source pole now, simply move it to the destination, then pile the rest of them from the spare pole onto the destination pole.

For example when *n* is 4...

[image: Hanoi - Step 1]
First move three onto the spare pole (worry how to do this later).

[image: Hanoi - Step 2]
Now move one ring from the source pole to the destination pole.

[image: Hanoi - Step 3]
Now move three rings from the spare pole to the destination pole
(again, we can worry about how to do this later).

[image: Hanoi - Step 4]
We have finished!

**More succinctly...**

To move *n* rings from A to C using B as spare:

- if *n* is 1

  - just do it,
- otherwise...

  - move *n-1* rings from A to B using C as spare
  - move one ring from A to C
  - move *n-1* rings from B to C using A as spare

As with most recursive solutions we have to treat some base case specially - here the base case occurs where we have only one ring to move.

**How to do it in C**

```
/* Tower of Hanoi - the answer */
/* How to move four rings from pin 1 to pin 3 using pin 2 as spare */
#include <stdio.h>

void move(n, A, C, B)
  /* number to move, source pole, destination pole and
     spare pole respectively */
  int n, A, B, C; {
    if (n == 1) {
      printf("Move from %d to %d.\n", A, C);
    } else {
      move(n - 1, A, B, C);
      move(1, A, C, B);
      move(n - 1, B, C, A);
    }
  }

  main() {
    move(4, 1, 3, 2);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compact implementation in Lisp: http://www.kernelthread.com/projects/hanoi/html/gcl.html. It is certainly recursive, but I did not verify it's correctness.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
discs = 3
T = [range(discs, 0, -1), [], []]

def show_towers():
    """Render a picture of the current state of the towers"""
    def render_disc(t, y):
        return ("-"*(t[y]*2-1) if y < len(t) else "|").center(discs*2)

    for y in range(discs):  
        print " ".join(render_disc(t, discs-y-1) for t in T)
    print "="*(discs*6+3)


def move(n, source, destination):
    """Recursively move n discs from source to destination"""
    while n > 0:
        temp = 3 - source - destination 
        move(n-1, source, temp)
        T[destination].append(T[source].pop())
        show_towers() 
        n, source = n-1, temp    # Simulate tail recursion


show_towers()
move(discs, 0, 2)
```

output for discs = 3

```
  -      |      |   
 ---     |      |   
-----    |      |   
=====================
  |      |      |   
 ---     |      |   
-----    |      -   
=====================
  |      |      |   
  |      |      |   
-----   ---     -   
=====================
  |      |      |   
  |      -      |   
-----   ---     |   
=====================
  |      |      |   
  |      -      |   
  |     ---   ----- 
=====================
  |      |      |   
  |      |      |   
  -     ---   ----- 
=====================
  |      |      |   
  |      |     ---  
  -      |    ----- 
=====================
  |      |      -   
  |      |     ---  
  |      |    ----- 
=====================
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs video lectures](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/)** contain helpful tips on solving this problem and a wealth of knowledge besides.

Answer (score 0):

See [wikipedia towers of hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) article for the description of recursive algorithm.

It goes something like this:

```
#include <iostream>   // ostream
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <deque> // I can iterate over towers & print state,<stack> works as well
#include <boost/array.hpp>   // just a wrapper for array
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>  // easy one line for_each iterating

using namespace std;

typedef std::deque< int > tower_t;  // stack works as well, deque for printing
typedef boost::array< tower_t ,3 > towers_t;  // 3 towers

enum peg { A = 0, B = 1, C = 2 };
```

---

Printing:

```
ostream & show(ostream & os, const tower_t & t)
{
    os << "[";
    for_each (t.begin(), t.end(), os << boost::lambda::_1 );
    return os << "]";
}

ostream & show(ostream & os, const towers_t & t)
{
    show(os, t[0]); show(os, t[1]); show(os, t[2]);
    return os;
}
```

---

Solve:

```
void move(peg from, peg to, towers_t & t)
{
    // show move and state before move
    cout << "mv: " << t[from].back() << " " << from << " --> " << to << "\t\t";
    show(cout, t); cout << " --> ";

    // the actual move: move top peg `from` stick `to` stick (and `pop` old top)
    t[to].push_back(t[from].back());
    t[from].pop_back();

    // show state after move
    show(cout, t); cout << endl;
}

// move n discs from A to B via C
void move(int n, peg from, peg to, peg via, towers_t & t)
{
    if (n == 1) { move(from, to, t); return; }

    move(n-1, from, via, to, t);
    move(from, to, t);
    move(n-1, via, to, from, t);

    return;
}
```

---

Usage, solve tower with 4 pegs:

```
int main()
{
    towers_t ttt;
    tower_t & first_tower(ttt[0]);
    first_tower.push_back(4);
    first_tower.push_back(3);
    first_tower.push_back(2);
    first_tower.push_back(1);

    move(first_tower.size(), A, C, B, ttt); // move n from A to C via B
}
```

Solved 3 towers with 4 pegs on the first tower, the biggest peg has the highest number, the smallest one is 1.

Output (`mv: PegX FromTower ---> ToTower`) followed by state before and after move, each tower from left to right showing pegs from bottom to top - top is on right:

```
mv: 1 0 --> 1       [4321][][] --> [432][1][]
mv: 2 0 --> 2       [432][1][] --> [43][1][2]
mv: 1 1 --> 2       [43][1][2] --> [43][][21]
mv: 3 0 --> 1       [43][][21] --> [4][3][21]
mv: 1 2 --> 0       [4][3][21] --> [41][3][2]
mv: 2 2 --> 1       [41][3][2] --> [41][32][]
mv: 1 0 --> 1       [41][32][] --> [4][321][]
mv: 4 0 --> 2       [4][321][] --> [][321][4]
mv: 1 1 --> 2       [][321][4] --> [][32][41]
mv: 2 1 --> 0       [][32][41] --> [2][3][41]
mv: 1 2 --> 0       [2][3][41] --> [21][3][4]
mv: 3 1 --> 2       [21][3][4] --> [21][][43]
mv: 1 0 --> 1       [21][][43] --> [2][1][43]
mv: 2 0 --> 2       [2][1][43] --> [][1][432]
mv: 1 1 --> 2       [][1][432] --> [][][4321]
```