# Towers of Hanoi with 3 parameters in C++, Tower(Disk, from, to)

Tags: c++, recursion

I have been trying to figure out how to implement a recursive function with just 3 parameters: Tower(Disk, from, to).  I did a lot of research on google. All the results came up with the 4 parameters recursive function, (disk, a, b, c). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

`typedef void (*towersActionFn)(unsigned short fromPost, unsigned short endPost);`

`void solveTowers(unsigned short nDisks, unsigned short start, unsigned short end, towersActionFn f);`

the towersActionFn is only used to display the solution.

Comment: If you've been trying to figure it out, how about posting the code you have so far instead of leaving 100% of the legwork to other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Pegs are counted 0 to 2

void Tower(int Disk, int Startpeg, int Endpeg)
{
    if(Disc <= 0)  //Sanity check
        return;

    if(Disc == 1)
        cout << "Move disk from "<<Startpeg<<" to "<<Endpeg<<endl;
    else
    {
        int Other = 3 - Startpeg - Endpeg;
        Tower(Disc-1, Startpeg,  Other);
        Tower(1, Startpeg, Endpeg); //Inline output would do here... Calling for message consistency.
        Tower(Disc-1, Other, Endpeg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223305/tower-of-hanoi-recursive-algorithm)

Comment: Thank you for the respond, but i believe i didnt word my question correctly. I am trying to implement the function with just the starting peg, and the destination peg in the parameter, and of course the # of disks. For example. void Tower(int Disk, int Startpeg, int Endpeg)

Comment: So, how have you defined that function, where are you stuck?