# Towers of Hanoi Explanation

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I'm a beginner to python and would like to know what the role of the `if` statement is in this Towers of Hanoi function:

```
def hanoi(ndisks, startPeg=1, endPeg=3):
    if ndisks:
        hanoi(ndisks-1, startPeg, 6-startPeg-endPeg)
        print "Move disk %d from peg %d to peg %d" % (ndisks, startPeg, endPeg)
        hanoi(ndisks-1, 6-startPeg-endPeg, endPeg)

hanoi(ndisks=4)
```

Comment: Shoot, I don't know how to mark out my whitespace when posting my question...

Comment: when you are typing in a question or answer there is a code format button above the text box with some brackets {} as its icon, highlight your code then click that.

Comment: You're not asking a real question here. If this is "your" function, what don't you understand about it? Do you understand the Python syntax? Do you understand the underlying algorithm?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the underlying algorithm I guess. Mainly why there is an if statement. I apologize, I'm still very new to this.

Comment: the if statement makes sure that ndisks is bigger than 1

Comment: If that's the case, why would it not be:
if ndisks>1:? I'm just trying to figure this out

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped greater than or equal to 1. That's a common way to express that in python

Comment: I've suggested an edit to clarify the nature of your question.

Comment: you should check out [this answer in - Tower of Hanoi: Recursive Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259294/7541700)

Answer (score 4):

A recursive algorithm needs a terminal condition which usually represents the simplest case of the algorithm.  For Towers of Hanoi the simplest case is when there are zero disks to move, don't do anything.

In Python, one condition of "falseness" is any numeric version of zero, so technically if anyone passed in a negative number to your algorithm it would fail, so it would be better to check for `if ndisks > 0`.  This stops the recursion when ndisks==0.

If there are a positive number (n) of disks to move, the recursive algorithm is:

1. Move n-1 disks from start peg to "other" peg.
2. Move the n<sup>th</sup> disk from start to end peg.
3. Move n-1 disks from "other" peg to end peg.

The above describes the rest of your code, with the terminal condition being zero disks.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottWaldron If Mark's answer was sufficient, you should consider marking it as correct.

Comment: you should check out [this answer in - Tower of Hanoi: Recursive Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259294/7541700)

Comment: To help visualize your code execution use []Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) visualization tool