# Recursion in Towers of hanoi

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I have read the Towers of Hanoi problem statement and the solution as well. The solution states that when you have to move a set of N disks from A to B, use C as temp and transfer N-1 disks from A to C. Then transfer Nth disk from A to B and then transfer the N-1 disks from C to B. I know that the problem has reduced in size and therefore a contender for implementation  recursively. However, we cannot transfer more than 1 disk at a time. How can we transfer N-1 disks in the first place.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25625964/489590 for more details.

Comment: Transfer `N-1` disks the same way you transferred `N` disks, recursively. When you get down to one disk, the transfer is trivial.

Comment: @Srinath Kattula: If you tag this question with C++ add some source code please or remove the tag.

Comment: @BrianCain Lol! @Srinath Kattula, we can perform `N-1` transfers, by performing transfer of one disk `N-1` times. If it's what you are asking. Hope it isn't.

Comment: @Srinath I advise you to study first how recursion works using a simpler example, for instance the fibonacci sequence. Once you can manage recursion well, turn back to this problem.

Comment: Hi . Thanks all. @usar, I did it just that I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

By using the recursion. See also [Tower of Hanoi: Recursive Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223305/tower-of-hanoi-recursive-algorithm) and the wikipedia page

The recursion is as follow: You know how to move 1 disc, suppose you know how to move n-1 discs, how do you move n discs?

The "suppose" part is your recursion: You move 10 discs by moving 9, then 1 then 9.
To move the 9 discs, you move 8, then 1, then 8.
To move the 8 discs...
...
To move the 2 discs, you move 1, then 1, then 1.

Answer (score 0):

That's the recursive step. Transfer `N-1` disks from A to C using the same algorithm that transfers `N` disks from A to B. If `N` is one, then simply move the single disk. (Or, equivalnently, if `N` is zero, do nothing).

In pseudocode:

```
move(N, A, B):
    if (N > 0)
        move(N-1, A, C)
        move_single_disk(A, B)
        move(N-1, C, B)
```