# Why does the 'disc' value in Towers of Hanoi not decrement to 0 in 'disc' amount of calls?

Tags: javascript, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am befuddled by the recursive solution for Towers of Hanoi that decrements a **disc** argument on each recursive call without starting at the initiated value of **disc** nor ending the recursion after **disc** amount of calls.

Shouldn't **disc - 1**  reach the value **0** after **disc** amount of calls? Where is the magician's hand in this elegant trick? Why does each new call seem to be working on its own **disc** value rather than the original argument?

```
function hanoi(disc, src, dst, aux) {
  if (disc === 0) {
    var disk = src.pop();
    dst.push(disk);
  } else {
    hanoi(disc-1, src, aux, dst);
    var disk = src.pop();
    dst.push(disk);
    hanoi(disc-1, aux, dst, src);
  }
}

hanoi(10, [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [], []);
```

Comment: Do you know what a local variable is? Each call *does* get its own `disc` variable.

Comment: Okay, I buy that. But take the recursive factorial solution for example, why doesn't `n * factorial(n - 1)` factor `n` as **0** in the beginning and why does its recursive call decrement `n` in a linear way with its own localized variable of `n - 1` ?

Comment: There's a fuller explanation of the recursion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223305/tower-of-hanoi-recursive-algorithm).  This covers part of what you asked.

Comment: Thanks, @Prune! I've finally earned the authority to up-vote so I've casted mine for what it's worth! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorial is linear recursion.  Towers of Hanoi is a double recursion: each deeper level requires 2 recursions for each time its called.  Thus, moving **N** disks requires **2^N - 1** total moves.

The algorithm reads something like this:

If this is the largest disk:
  move it to the destination peg; now we're done.

Otherwise:
  move the next disc down to the third peg;
  move this one to the destination peg;
  move that next disk to the destination peg;

It's this "otherwise" part that takes two calls for one.

Does that clarify anything for you?

Comment: Oh, I see those two new local `disc` variables now! They are decrementing in their own local scopes, and when one reaches `disc === 0`, it returns with pushing the `src` value to the `dst' peg which is `aux` in the first call and then the second recursive call ends with pushing the `src` value which is from the `aux` peg to the `dst` peg. **One last question** though, @Prune and thank you for your explanation by the way, it is quite suffice. Shouldn't the first recursive call to `hanoi(disc-1, src, aux, dst)` start again from the top and call itself again, how does it run the code below it?

Comment: It calls itself to move **disc** to the aux peg.  When those 2^(disc-1)-1 moves are done, control returns to do the pop-push that moves **disc**.  Then it continues, another recursive call to do the second half of the work: moving all the smaller disks from the aux peg to sit on the one we just moved.