# Algorithm to insert 1 piece into imperfect Tower of Hanoi

Tags: algorithm, logic, towers-of-hanoi

I'm doing a program for my robot arm to build the tower of Hanoi. I got the algorithm working on a standing tower (replacing the tower to a different place using only 3 locations).

*Locations:* A, B, C
*Pieces:* 5

I'd like to build up the tower step-by-step (I'll place a piece on location C, the arm places the piece onto/into the tower on location A). The code is working if the current piece goes on top.

**Question: Is there a (recursive) algorithm to place a piece into the tower using only 3 places (A is the current tower, C is the new piece, B empty)?**

EDIT: I'm not trying to build the tower on a different place. I'm asking for an algorithm, that could place a piece on C into the tower on A (let's say tower is 5-3-2-1 and I place the final '4' piece on C. The algorithm should place it into the right place for it to become 5-4-3-2-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tower of Hanoi: Recursive Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223305/tower-of-hanoi-recursive-algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already *"...got the algorithm working on a standing tower (replacing the tower to a different place using only 3 locations)..."*, so proceed as follows:

1. Determine how many pieces in stack A are smaller than the one on stack C. Call this number *k*. It could be zero, in which case you can just move the piece from stack C to stack A in one operation. If not:
2. Completely ignore the pieces in stack A that are below the top *k* pieces. Perform this and the following steps as if they don't exist. Now use your existing algorithm (to move a stack completely to another location), to move the top *k* elements from stack A to position B. The pieces we ignored do not participate in this move.
3. Then move the piece from stack C to stack A. Now also ignore this piece in the next step. So we can act as if stack A is empty now.
4. Use your algorithm again to move stack B to location A. Again, we ignore the pieces that are already at location A: they do not move during this step.

Comment: Yes, after a day of thinking I realized I just have to offset a stack as if there was already one placed. Thank you!