# Tower of the boxes

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

We have `N` boxes. Each box has 3 params: width, length, height.

I need to write a function that generates the highest possible tower using this boxes.
Function must obey the following rule: all params of bottom box should be bigger than box above it.

### Example

Let's say we have a box described as int array `{width, length, height} -> {1, 2, 5}`, then:

input: `boxes = {{2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 5, 4}, {7, 7, 1}}`

output: `8` since `{4, 5, 4} greater than {2, 2, 3} greater than {1, 1, 1}`

### Solution

I have found one solution that I can not understand.

```
void sortArrDesc(int[][] array) {
  Arrays.sort(array, new java.util.Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
      return -1 * Integer.compare(a[2], b[2]);
    }
  });
}

boolean canPlaceOnTop(int prevBoxIndex, int currBoxIndex, int[][] boxes) {
  if (prevBoxIndex == -1) return true;
  int[] bottomBox = boxes[prevBoxIndex];
  int[] topBox = boxes[currBoxIndex];

  return (bottomBox[0] > topBox[0] && 
          bottomBox[1] > topBox[1] && 
          bottomBox[2] > topBox[2]);
}

int getHighestTower(int prevBoxIndex, int currBoxIndex, int[][] boxes) {
  if (currBoxIndex == boxes.length) return 0;

  int nextBoxIndex = currBoxIndex + 1;

  int heightWithCurrBox = 0;

  if (canPlaceOnTop(prevBoxIndex, currBoxIndex, boxes)) { 
    int currentBoxHeight = boxes[currBoxIndex][2];
    int heightNextBox = getHighestTower(currBoxIndex, nextBoxIndex, boxes);
    heightWithCurrBox = heightNextBox + currentBoxHeight;
  }

  int heightWithoutCurrBox = 
            getHighestTower(prevBoxIndex, nextBoxIndex, boxes);


  return Math.max(heightWithCurrBox, heightWithoutCurrBox);
}

int getHighestTower(int[][] boxes) {
  sortArrDesc(boxes);
  return getHighestTower(-1, 0, boxes);
}
```

I don't understand what exactly `getHighestTower` function do.

I mean when for example, I call function `Math.sqrt(5)` I understand that I will get square root of 5. But here, in `getHighestTower` function something strange happening.

It is clear that call `getHighestTower(-1, 0, boxes)` will return the highest tower.

But! When we do recursive calls, I do not understand what they means.
`getHighestTower(prevBoxIndex, nextBoxIndex, boxes)`

What does this line means?

It seems like that call should return max possible height starting from `nextBox`, but then why do we need to use `prevBoxIndex`?

Moreover, this call `getHighestTower(currBoxIndex, nextBoxIndex, boxes);` looks like do the same, but instead of `prevBoxIndex` we use `currBoxIndex` why is that?

P.S. I have already found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280208/tower-of-boxes-stacking-cubes), but it doesn't contain any useful information.

Comment: `prevBoxIndex` is the index of the box on top of the stack (that box is needed by the `canPlaceOnTop` method). `currBoxIndex` is the index of a box which may or may not be added to the stack. This is basically a depth-first search.

Comment: Why is not the output 11 ? I see the following output is valid : `{4,5,4} -> {3,3,3} -> {2,2,3} -> {1,1,1}` ? Is it a requirement that all dimensions should be strictly larger to define "bigger" ?

Comment: @user3386109 could you explain in more details why we need  `prevBoxIndex`?

Comment: For example, `prevBoxIndex` is 100, and `currBoxIndex` is 101. Then the function will check if box 101 can be placed on box 100. If it can, the first recursive call is `getHighestTower(101,102,boxes)`. The second recursive call is `getHighestTower(100,102,boxes)`. In other words, the first call uses box 101. The second call skips box 101, and finds the best height starting with an attempt to put box 102 on top of box 100.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you!. According to your comment recursive calls work in the following manner:
The `getHighestTower(101,102,boxes)` call calculates the highest possible tower using  `h1 = boxes[101] + boxes[102] + ... + the lowest box`.
And the `getHighestTower(101,102,boxes)` call calculates the highest possible tower using `h2 = boxes[100] + boxes[102] + ... + the lowest box`.
If it's true, then why we add height of box[101] to result of the `getHighestTower(101,102,boxes)` if it already calculated by recursion?

Comment: @user3386109 In other words why do we never use `boxes[prevBoxIndex]` height?

Comment: Because if that box is used, then `heightWithCurrBox = heightNextBox + currentBoxHeight;` adds that height. OTOH, if that box is skipped, we never want to add that height. Keep in mind that `currentBoxIndex` at one level of recursion is the same as `prevBoxIndex` at the next level of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved like this:

1. Sort the boxes by height.
2. Then the problem is to look for the increasing subsequence whose sum of heights is maximum - here "increasing" would mean :

`currLength > prevLength && currWidth > prevWidth && currHeight > prevHeight`

For the input `{{2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 5, 4}, {7, 7, 1}}`

lets say the sorted by height array is :

`{7,7,1}, {1,1,1}, {2,2,3}, {3,3,3}, {4,5,4}`

then the increasing subsequence with the above criterion is

`{1,1,1}, {3,3,3}, {4,5,4}`

Then height is `1 + 3 + 4 = 8`.

Why do you need to sort by height first ? 
Because, lets say the input is

`{{4,5,4}, {2,2,3}, {1,1,1}, {3,3,3}, {7,7,1}}`

and is not sorted by height, then the increasing subsequence by above criterion would yield

`{1,1,1}, {3,3,3}`

and it gives answer as `1 + 3 = 4` which is not optimal.

Code in Java:

```
 private static int getHeighestTower( int[][] x ) {
    Arrays.sort( x, new Comparator<int[]>() {
      @Override
      public int compare( int[] a, int[] b ) {
        return a[2] - b[2];
      }
    });

    int[] L = new int[x.length];
    Arrays.fill(L,1);
    int max = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int hi = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
      hi = x[i][2];
      int lastAdded = 0;
      for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
        if ( aBiggerThanB(x[i], x[j]) ) {
          if ( L[i] < 1 + L[j] ) {
            L[i] = 1 + L[j];
            hi += x[j][2];
            lastAdded = x[j][2];
          } else if ( L[i] == 1 + L[j] ) {
            hi = Math.max( hi, hi - lastAdded + x[j][2]);
          }
        }
      }
      h = Math.max( h, hi);
      max = Math.max( max, L[i] );
    }

    return h;
 }

 private static boolean aBiggerThanB( int[] a, int[] b ) {
    return a[0] > b[0] && a[1] > b[1] && a[2] > b[2];
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how is your answer connected with my question? I understand why we sort boxes. I do not understand what recursion does, because of two params `prevBoxIndex` and `currBoxIndex`. I can not understand the idea behind what recursion calls return.

Comment: @NoNameQA I don't think the code with recursion is the correct code, for example : `int heightNextBox = getHighestTower(currBoxIndex, nextBoxIndex, boxes);` why would you compute the height with next box before computnig height with current box?

Comment: The code works perfectly. It is not mine. And I don't understand why it works. And this what I'm trying to find out. If you scroll code to the end you will see that it sorts boxes before start do the recursion calls.

Comment: Your code works incorrectly for the following input: `{ {7, 3, 8}, {9, 3, 7}, {8, 2, 6}, {6, 4, 4}, {5, 3, 3}, {4, 2, 2} }`

Comment: @NoNameQA Got it. Thanks for the test. The algorithm should not actually look at longest increasing subsequence, it should calculate increasing subsequence with maximum sum of heights. I updated my answer and also the code. It should work now.